# com.sabre.universalservices.base.security.AuthenticationException: errors.authentication.USG_AUTHENTICATION_NOT_ALLOWED

Tags: sabre

I am checking the Sabre API's in SoapUI. Taken ref. for SoapUI from https://github.com/SabreDevStudio/SabreAPIsWorkflows.

When I am trying to run a test-step in SoapUI, I am getting the response with error as :
AuthenticationException: errors.authentication.USG_AUTHENTICATION_NOT_ALLOWED.

request payload :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sec="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:mes="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" xmlns:ns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/utility">
      <wsse:UsernameToken>
        <wsse:Username>${#Project#Username}</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password>${#Project#Password}</wsse:Password>
        <Organization>${#Project#Organization}</Organization>
        <Domain>DEFAULT</Domain>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
    <mes:MessageHeader mes:id="?" mes:version="?">
      <mes:From>
        <mes:PartyId mes:type="?">1212</mes:PartyId>
      </mes:From>
      <mes:To>
        <mes:PartyId mes:type="?">2323</mes:PartyId>
      </mes:To>
      <mes:CPAId>${#Project#Organization}</mes:CPAId>
      <mes:ConversationId>${#Project#ConversationID}</mes:ConversationId>
      <mes:Service mes:type="Sabre">BargainFinderMaxRQ</mes:Service>
      <mes:Action>BargainFinderMaxRQ</mes:Action>
      <mes:MessageData>
        <mes:MessageId>1001</mes:MessageId>
        <mes:Timestamp>2012-06-07T10:00:01</mes:Timestamp>
        <mes:TimeToLive>2013-06-06T23:59:59</mes:TimeToLive>
      </mes:MessageData>
    </mes:MessageHeader>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ Target="Production" Version="1.9.2" ResponseType="OTA" ResponseVersion="1.9.2" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <POS>
        <!--Source PseudoCityCode="PCC"-->
        <Source PseudoCityCode="${#Project#Organization}">
          <RequestorID ID="1" Type="1">
            <CompanyName Code="TN">TN</CompanyName>
          </RequestorID>
        </Source>
      </POS>
      <OriginDestinationInformation>
        <DepartureDateTime>${#TestCase#OutboundDepartureDateTime}</DepartureDateTime>
        <DepartureWindow>02002000</DepartureWindow>
        <OriginLocation LocationCode="${#Project#ItineraryOrigin}" />
        <DestinationLocation LocationCode="${#Project#ItineraryDestination}" />
        <TPA_Extensions>
          <SegmentType Code="O" />
        </TPA_Extensions>
      </OriginDestinationInformation>
      <OriginDestinationInformation>
        <DepartureDateTime>${#TestCase#ReturnDepartureDateTime}</DepartureDateTime>
        <DepartureWindow>04002200</DepartureWindow>
        <OriginLocation LocationCode="${#Project#ItineraryDestination}" />
        <DestinationLocation LocationCode="${#Project#ItineraryOrigin}" />
        <TPA_Extensions>
          <SegmentType Code="O" />
        </TPA_Extensions>
      </OriginDestinationInformation>
      <TravelPreferences>
        <FlightTypePref MaxConnections="2" PreferLevel="Only" />
        <ns:FareRestrictPref PreferLevel="Only">
          <ns:AdvResTicketing AdvResInd="false" AdvTicketingInd="false" />
          <ns:StayRestrictions StayRestrictionsInd="false" />
          <ns:VoluntaryChanges VolChangeInd="false" />
        </ns:FareRestrictPref>
        <CabinPref Cabin="Y" PreferLevel="Only" />
        <TPA_Extensions>
          <TripType Value="Return" />
        </TPA_Extensions>
      </TravelPreferences>
      <TravelerInfoSummary>
        <SeatsRequested>1</SeatsRequested>
        <AirTravelerAvail>
          <PassengerTypeQuantity Code="ADT" Quantity="1" />
        </AirTravelerAvail>
      </TravelerInfoSummary>
      <TPA_Extensions>
        <IntelliSellTransaction>
          <RequestType Name="50ITINS" />
        </IntelliSellTransaction>
      </TPA_Extensions>
    </OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

response received:

```
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap-env:Header>
      <eb:MessageHeader eb:version="1.0" soap-env:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader">
         <eb:From>
            <eb:PartyId eb:type="?">2323</eb:PartyId>
         </eb:From>
         <eb:To>
            <eb:PartyId eb:type="?">1212</eb:PartyId>
         </eb:To>
         <eb:CPAId>****</eb:CPAId>
         <eb:ConversationId>SWS-Test-****</eb:ConversationId>
         <eb:Service eb:type="Sabre">BargainFinderMaxRQ</eb:Service>
         <eb:Action>ErrorRS</eb:Action>
         <eb:MessageData>
            <eb:MessageId>607896186247240150</eb:MessageId>
            <eb:Timestamp>2018-09-19T05:10:24</eb:Timestamp>
            <eb:RefToMessageId>1001</eb:RefToMessageId>
         </eb:MessageData>
      </eb:MessageHeader>
      <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext"/>
   </soap-env:Header>
   <soap-env:Body>
      <soap-env:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap-env:Client.AuthenticationNotAllowed</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Authentication is not allowed for this service. Please use SessionCreateRQ</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <StackTrace>com.sabre.universalservices.base.security.AuthenticationException: errors.authentication.USG_AUTHENTICATION_NOT_ALLOWED</StackTrace>
         </detail>
      </soap-env:Fault>
   </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope
```

Can anyone help in this?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because instead of using a Binary Security Token, your request is sending user, passcode, etc. That data should be sent first with SessionCreateRQ which will return a BST, then you use the token in the subsequent BargainFinderMaxRQ call. Your "Security" node should look like so:

```
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/utility">
  <wsse:BinarySecurityToken>{{token}}</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
</wsse:Security>
```